# How can one know if an activity is started without a transition?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have a use case where I mostly start an activity with a transition, but that's not the case when opening it from the navigation drawer.

To keep the transition smooth I have a `Transition.TransitionListener` in which I trigger some UI updating when the transition is done.

So I have something like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        // ...
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
            sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
                // ...
                @Override
                public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                    doSomeUiUpdating();
                }
            });
        } else { // Pre-Lollipop
            doSomeUiUpdating();
        }
    }
}
```

This works well when starting the Activity with the animation, but **how can I know if the Activity was started without a transition so that I can call `doSomeUiUpdating()`?**

I'm sure there must be a simple method in `Activity`, `Window`, `Transition` or somewhere that I have overlooked. I don't want to relay on the calling Activity to set some bundle that telling if the animation is showing or not.

Comment: i will assume its the same logic as you have (if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { doSomeUiUpdating(); .... ) before the code you have to start an activity

Comment: and transitions were added in API 19 (KITKAT) so you need to check before that not LOLLIPOP -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3yMV5am-Xo

Comment: The thing is that - as I try to say in the first line - the activity (even though on Lollipop+) is most often started with the transition, but not when the user starts the activity from the navigation drawer.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you can wait a second until the nav drawer is closed and then do something if that's an issue -- http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html#onDrawerClosed(android.view.View)

Comment: When opening the activity from the navigation drawer I don't have the shared element (an ImageView) to animate into the next activity. (I have the shared element when starting the activity from elsewhere.)

Comment: Just a dummy thought: maybe you can rely on `getTargets()` method of `Transition` (`sharedElementEnterTransition.getTargets().isEmpty()`) if it is empty or not? It's not null anyway and numbers of TargetViews maybe the solution here..

Comment: Isn't sharedElementEnterTransition null when there is no transition?

Comment: @drakyoko no, it's not null, though it was also my initial thought.

Comment: The transition itself (windowSharedElementEnterTransition) is described in the theme for the app. From what I've seen so far the objects describing the transition are always the same. I haven't found any info about the shared elements themselves. @KonstantinLoginov: The targets are always empty..

Comment: Hi. How about putting a flag into the starting Intent ?

Comment: @Lev: Yes, that's the only solution I have so far. But as I say in question; I ideally don't want to relay on the caller of the activity to set the flags right. However, I might have to go for that way of doing it.

Comment: @RoyS I'm sorry, apparently I did not read that last sentence in your post. My apologies :)

Comment: Did you try `onTransitionStart` of `TransitionListener` to set some boolean `isAnimationStarted`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `onTransitionStart` of `TransitionListener` to set some boolean `isAnimationStarted`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean isAnimationStarted = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        // ...
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
            sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
                // ...
                @Override
                public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                    doSomeUiUpdating();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransitionStarted(Transition transition) {
                    isAnimationStarted = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void onStart() {
        if (!isAnimationStarted) {
            doSomeUiUpdating();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution. :)

Comment: But won't this create a possible problem - because the callback implies an async execution, isn't it possible that even if the animation is upcoming, onStart will be called before the onTransitionStarted is called?

Comment: In fact, I just tested it and it was exactly as I said - in my case, onStart was always called before any of the callbacks, so isAnimationStarted was always false there. So, this method certainly doesn't help to determine if the activity was started with/without transition.

Comment: Did you find the right way to do this? As the comment of @NeverwinterMoon says, this doesn't exactly solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are starting an `Activity`, you'll be making use of an `Intent` to start it. You can add extras to `Intent`s and check for them in the `onCreate()` of the called `Activity`.

Let's assume that we have 2 Activities – `ActivityA`, and `ActivityB`.

Now, let's assume that `ActivityA` is the calling `Activity`, and that `ActivityB` is the called `Activity`.

In `ActivityA`, let's say you've written some code to start `ActivityB` with a `SharedElementTransition`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent startActivityBIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityB.class);
    startActivityBIntent.putExtra("IS_SHARED_ELEMENT_TRANSITION_ENABLED", true);
    ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), view, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view));
    startActivity(startActivityBIntent, activityOptionsCompat);
}
```

Now, if you notice above, I've passed an `Intent` extra with the `putExtra()` method. I've passed a `Boolean` value of true because I intend to start the Activity with a `SharedElementTransition`.

Now in `ActivityB`'s `onCreate()` method, you can just check for the boolean value passed to the `Intent`. If you passed false, then you can add a conditional statement and perform your UI updating there. I've given you a small snippet below to help you get started:

```
private static final String isSharedElementTransitionEnabled = "IS_SHARED_ELEMENT_TRANSITION_ENABLED";    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    // If you are postponing your SharedElementTransition, don't forget to call postponeEnterTransition() and override onPreDraw()

    if (!getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(isSharedElementTransitionEnabled)) {
        //Do your UI updation here
    }
}
```

The good thing about doing it this way is that you can then have full control over how your content transitions and your shared element transitions will play out.